# How to use/learn Video4Linux2 (On Screen Display) Output APIs?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

My latest microprocessor( Freescale iMX233 ) has 8 hardware overlay plus inbuilt YUV to RGB conversion functionality. They have exposed these functionality through v4l2 driver. [v4l2 Documentation](http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/video4linux/API/V4L2_API/spec-single/v4l2.html)  doesn't say it properly that how to use it. Is there any tutorial available or any reference code which I can use to learn v4l2 apis?

Comment: Well, I got it by reading its driver code.I will post detailed tutorial here in some time.

Comment: Hi it would be very helpful if you provide detailed tutorial waiting for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SunnyShah do you have the detailed tutorial which I can take a look at?

Answer (score 12):

The V4L2 API isn't the greatest API out there and it is not very easy to use it.

There are however a few resources available.

The first one is the "official" [V4L2 doc](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/book1.htm)

The series of article written on [lwn](http://lwn.net/Articles/203924/) focus more on the driver side of V4L2, but still they are a very interesting reading if you want to understand how V4L2 works and to use it right.

Finally, this simple but quite complete [video capture example](https://web.archive.org/web/20110520211256/http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/capture-example.html) is a good code basis for anyone wanting to use the V4L2 API. It shows the 3 ways (memory mapped buffers, read() calls and application allocated buffers) of acquiring data through a camera sensor.

Comment: I understood it by reading my hardware manual and V4l2 driver.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen your comment, but since the question was reasked by Karim, I thought it would be nice to have a more complete answer with a few good resources on V4L2 (as a kind of reference for stackoverflow)

Comment: The capture example page is broken. Does anyone know any similar resource?