# Taking an Image from a Webcam in Ubuntu Using C

Tags: c, linux, image, webcam

I am trying to use my webcam (Creative Live! Cam Chat) to take an image in C/C++ and save it to a certain folder(running Ubuntu). Ideally I'm looking to something as simple as possible despite it not being the most elegant solution.

So far I've found v4l2grab which I find incredibly confusing to understand, and also doesn't seem to work with the Creative webcam (returns a black picture that is 5Kb in size) although it does seem to work with the webcam installed as a part of my laptop.

Are there any simple C libraries or code that I could use to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webcam library for C on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278112/webcam-library-for-c-on-linux)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a good library for the purpose (please add comment and tell me if there is one :-)). Note: for some uses, eg. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is just fine, and [if it is enough for you, definitely do use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278112/webcam-library-for-c-on-linux). But if you want more, read on.

So you should just write your own code to use it, it's not particularly hard. Here's one related question: [How to use/learn Video4Linux2 (On Screen Display) Output APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738828/how-to-use-learn-video4linux2-on-screen-display-output-apis)

Some points to make learning easier:

- After calling an IOCTL, always check return status and print possible error message. You will be getting lots of these while you work, so just be systematic about it. I suggest a function like `check_error` shown below, and calling it always immediatly after any ioctl call.
- IMO a must: use IDE/editor, which can follow symbol to the actual header file (for example in Qt Creator, which is a fine pure C application IDE despite the name, hit F2 on symbol, and it will go even to system headers to show you where it is defined). Use this liberally on V4L2 related symbols and defines, and read comments in the header file, that's often the best documentation.
- Use the query ioctls and write functions to dump values they return in nice format. For example have function `void dump_cap(const struct v4l2_capability &cap) {...}`, and add a similar function for every struct you use in your code as you go.
- Don't be lazy about setting values inside structs you pass to IOCTL. Always initialize structs to 0 with `memset(&ioctl_struct_var, 0, sizeof(ioctl_struct_var));` after declaring them, and also if you reuse them (except when doing 'get-modify-set' operation on some settings, which is quite common with V4L2).
- If possible, have two (or more) different webcams (different resolutions, different brand), and test with both (all). This is easiest if you take video device as command line parameter, so you can just call your program with different argument for each cam you have.
- Small steps. Often ioctls may not return what you expect, so no point writing code which uses the returned data, before you have actually seen what the query returns for your cameras.

The `check_error` function mentioned above:

```
void check_error(int return_value_of_ioctl, const char *msg) {
    if (return_value_of_ioctl != -1) return; /* all ok */
    int eno = errno; /* just to avoid accidental clobbering of errno */
    fprintf(stderr, "error (%d) with %s: %s\n", eno, msg, strerror(eno));
    exit(1); /* optional, depending on how you want to work with your code */
}
```

Call that immediatly after every ioctl, for example:

```
struct v4l2_capability cap;
setmem(&cap, 0, sizeof(cap));
int r=ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &cap); 
check_error(r, "VIDIOC_QUERYCAP");
dump_querycap(&cap);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenCV. Use `cvCreatecameraCapture` (You can call it with argument 0 to get to the fault cam) to create an object and then call `cvQueryFrame` on that object. Calling `cvQueryFrame` each time will return a frame.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)? It's quite handy for all sorts of image getting and processing. The process of taking picture is well documented, but I suggest you look at something like [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture), if you do indeed decide to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`uvccapture`](https://github.com/csete/uvccapture/blob/master/uvccapture.c) source code. It is very simple, yet standard C which uses only V4L2 interface. `OpenCV` would also work, but it is more complicated to setup and compile.

Comment: Note about OpenCV being more compicated: just `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` in Ubuntu, and remember to add it to linking, asked before at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415236/ububtu-opencv-and-linking